# Apache Camel после исключения не выводит Message History. Какие могут быть причины?

Tags: java, camel

Message History включен, но почему-то не логируется. Может бывают исключительные ситуации?
Код к сожалению, показать не могу.

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.testapp.TestObject but has value: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@47bfd611 of type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache on: Message: [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type: com.testapp.TestObject with value org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@47bfd611. Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of org.apache.camel.StreamCache]]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type: com.testapp.TestObject with value org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@47bfd611]
  at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:101)
  at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.getBody(AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.java:66)
  at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.afterInvoke(AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.java:175)
  at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractCamelInvocationHandler$1.call(AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.java:112)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.invokeWithBody(AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.java:128)
  at org.apache.camel.component.bean.CamelInvocationHandler.doInvokeProxy(CamelInvocationHandler.java:45)
  at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractCamelInvocationHandler.java:82)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache to the required type: com.testapp.TestObject with value org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache@47bfd611
  at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:181)
  at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:99)
  ... 123 more
```